# Arduino response USSD command truncated

Tags: arduino, gsm, ussd, sim900

I'm trying to send a USSD string with Arduino/SIM900 module.
This is my code:

```
mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=0");
   delay(100);

   mySerial.println("AT+CUSD=1,\"*123#\"");
   delay(10000);
if (mySerial.available() >0)
  {

    while(mySerial.available() > 0)
    {
      incoming_char=mySerial.read(); //Get the character from the cellular serial port.

      Serial.print(incoming_char);

    }
 }
```

the problem is that, the response is truncated.
If I try to remove the row

```
mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=0");
```

the response is more long but always truncated

How to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to use `mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");`

Comment: with AT+CMGF=1 I receive OK but no USSD string: this is my answer AT+CMGF=1
AT+CUSD=1,"*123#"

OK

Comment: is `*123#` a valid command?  what is the response when you set `AT+CMGF=0`

- it would be great if you connect the modem to a serial terminal and pass commands from the pc manually and see what are the results

Comment: yes *123# is valid (credit of sim). With 'AT+CMGF=0' i receive: AT+CMGF=0
AT+CUSD=1,"*123#"

OK
if I remove CMGF row I receive the response, but it is trouncated: AT+CUSD=1,"*123#"

OK

+CUSD: 0,"RESPONSE TROUNCATED